# How do I make a hashtag a different color than the rest of the text in sketchware?

Tags: android, kotlin, javahelp, sketchware

How do I make a hashtag a different color than the rest of the text in sketchware

How do I make a hashtag a different color than the rest of the text in sketchware
I want to make the hashtag a different color than the rest of the people in sketchware
I tried many solutions, but I failed to find a solution. Help me as soon as possible

Comment: Can You add some more details about it? Sorry, but I don't understand that point. Where you showing your hashtag